# perl hash -- best way to re index to compact values

Tags: perl, hash

I have a multidimensional hash in perl with columns and rows.

What is the best way to compact / reindex it to:

- Remove Empty Columns
- Remove Empty Rows
- Reindex an individual item / cell with value to the next row index that is less than current row index
- Individual items / cells with values don't need to change columns just rows.

Thank You...

Here is a sample hash that is similar in structure to what I have:

```
foreach $i (1..5) {
  $column   = int(rand(10)) +1;

  foreach $j (1..10) {
    $row   = int(rand(10)) +1;
    $value = int(rand(1000)) +1;

    $hash{$column}{$row} = $value if !$hash{$column}{$row};
  }
}
```

+--------------------------------------------------+

I converted it an Array of an Array.

I was able to compact the columns but I'm unable to remove empty columns.  I know it has something to do with slice but can't figure out the correct syntax.

```
#AoA - Before#

$VAR1 = [
      undef,
      [
        undef,
        4,
        0,
        61,
        0,
        22
      ],
      [
        undef,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ],
      [
        undef,
        0,
        12,
        50,
        0,
        66
      ],
      [
        undef,
        70,
        42,
        22,
        0,
        0
      ]
    ];


foreach $column (0..@AoA -1) {
  ### Compact column
  @{$AoA[$column]} = grep { ($_) } @{$AoA[$column]};


  ### Remove empty column
  ### What is the correct syntax for this???
  # if(!(scalar @{$AoA[$column]}) ) {
  #  splice(@AoA, $column, 1);
  # }
}


#AoA - After#
$VAR1 = [
      [],
      [
        4,
        61,
        22
      ],
      [],
      [
        12,
        50,
        66
      ],
      [
        70,
        42,
        22
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: can you show an example of before and after the reindexing you mention?  better yet, run the code you show, show a dump of the datastructure (e.g. output of `print Data::Dumper::Dumper(\%hash)`), then show what it looks like after all the changes you want

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Data::Table](http://search.cpan.org/~ezdb/Data-Table-1.68/Table.pm), it provides several features that allow you to do what you want.

Example Table

```
my $t = new Data::Table([ ["John", 20], ["Kate", 18], ["Mike", 23] ], ["name", "age"], 0);
my $t1 = new Data::Table; # This is the final clean table
```

For example, get a new table without empty rows

```
$t1=$t->match_pattern('join('',$_)-> =~ //');
```

Find and delete empty columns

```
my $columns_keep = {};
$t->colsMap( sub { $columns_keep{ $_->[$colIndex] }="1" if $_->[0]; } );
$t1.addCols( $t->delCols( keys $columns_keep  ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with.  Seems to work pretty good.  Let me know if there is a better way.

Given an Array of Arrays.  Remove empty cells in a column and then remove empty columns.

Structure of variable (See edit of original question):  `$AoA[$column][$row]`

```
### Compact columns. 
foreach $column (0..@AoA -1) {
  @{$AoA[$column]} = grep { $_ } @{$AoA[$column]};
}

### Remove empty columns
@AoA = grep { scalar @{$_} } @AoA;
```